# Are Circles Triangles and Squares topologically homeomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to get the fundamental group of a square figured shape having four triangular subdivisions by its two diagonals using Van Kampen's Theorem. But The first question that came to my mind is that, Is a triangle and a circle homeomorphic? And If yes, then I can imagine it to be homeomorphic to a square too. But A square can be turned into a Torus. and Torus and Circle are not homeomorphic.
Where I'm making mistakes?

Comment: Do you mean just the boundary of a square/triangle, or also the interior?

Comment: Also, a square, even with interior, is not homeomorphic to a torus; only by 'gluing' can one turn a square into a torus, but that is obviously not bijective.

Comment: I'm considering only the boundary of the three figures. So, are the three figures homeomorphic? Circle, Square and triangle (taking only the boundary)

Comment: Certainly a square's boundary isn't homeomorphic to a torus.

Comment: So basically, as, for a given circle and a triangle, I can take a bijection from the given circle to a circle inscribed in the triangle, and then From that incircle we can define a bijection to the triangle as, from the centre of the circle taking a ray, each point of circle can be projected to a unique point of the triangle. So, by this way, we have shown that a circle and a triangle are homeomorphic. And then I guess, proceeding the same way, a circle should also be homeomorphic to a square.

Comment: I said that a square is not homeomorphic to a torus, and neither is a circle.

Comment: Yes, I got that. A circle or a square is not homeomorphic to a torus. As in Topology, we don't allow gluing and cutting while deforming a figure. So, that confusion regarding torus is clear to me. But the other question was that whether a circle triangle and a square are homeomorphic to each other or not. So for that, is my above argument correct?

Comment: Yes, those are certainly homeomorphic, as you have shown. What did you mean by 'deformed' in your original question?

Comment: It's a mistake. After reading your 2nd comment, I got the point that deformation is something else, a square can be turned into a torus, but that doesn't mean that it is a deformation.